# Controlling Process Name of my Jar

Tags: java

I wanted to know is there any way I could control the name the process my jar is starting, i.e,
I created a .jar file in java and whenever I am clicking on it, it is causing a process named javaw.exe and I want to control this name.
I want to do so because when I click on my jar file then if it already running it should stop and a new one should start, i.e., I want to run a new thread  (process) everytime I click on it by stopping the previous one.
If I kill the process named javaw.exe, all processes with name javaw.exe would die (if I am running more than one program) . So, I need to change its name.
Plz help.
Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with `javaw` running.  [From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html):

> The javaw command is identical to java, except that with javaw there is no associated console window. Use javaw when you don't want a command prompt window to appear. The javaw launcher will, however, display a dialog box with error information if a launch fails for some reason.

Ultimately, `javaw` runs your program without a console window.  Changing that name could lead to some serious issues later, so you'd want to keep that particular program name.

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel?  There are already standard ways to prevent two copies of the same program from running.    Typically it involves creating a "flag" file, since filesystems guarantee that directory updates are atomic.  On UNIX-like systems, the file would be /var/run/program-name.pid.  If it already exists, then the second copy will exit with an error.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a controller process, that manages your instances:

First you try to connect to the controller on localhost via tcp/ip at a specific port (your programs "name" from now) and if sucessful, you send a message like 'new instance started' to that controller. If the connection was not sucessful, you start a new controller-thread in the current vm (and send the message again to this thread)

the controller loops, waiting for messages and if one matches 'new instance started', it does what you describe.

such a controller can be built easily using a simple ServerSocket, a small HTTP-server or many other messaging libs.